# SWIFT: Associate CGPoint with image from array

Tags: arrays, swift, uiimageview, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a program in which a collection outlet is looped in order to give every image a CGpoint to determine its origin position and to apply a pan gesture to each image.

However, my problem is that when the pan gesture ends, the picture should snap back to its origin position which was determined in the beginning. But when I do,

```
if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended {

                for image in imageCollection {
                    image.center = positionOrigin
                }
```

the images move back to different positions/ the same positions as the other images.
I suppose this is due to the fact I have not associated a CGPoint origin with each image via index (e.g. it makes sense to use a dictionary?).
Anyone an idea how to solve this?

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var imageCollection: [UIImageView]!

    var positionOrigin: CGPoint!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        for image in imageCollection {
            positionOrigin = image.center
            let recognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.handlePan))
            recognizer.delegate = self
            image.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
        }
  }
     func handlePan(sender:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

        let translation = sender.translationInView(self.view)

        if let view = sender.view {
            view.center = CGPoint(x:view.center.x + translation.x,
                                  y:view.center.y + translation.y)
            sender.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)
        }
        if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended {

            for image in imageCollection {
                image.center = positionOrigin
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this part is the problem `var positionOrigin: CGPoint!`
it's value change in the loop, so in the end, it has only the last image position,
you can use subclass of the image with property **positionOrigin**   or use an array of positionOrigin to save the origin position of every image.

Comment: Yes, I already tried to make CGPoint an array and iterate through both of them, but somehow I am stuck. I always get an error message "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION" in the line where I append the image position.

    `@IBOutlet var imageCollection: [UIImageView]!
    var originPositions: [CGPoint]!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        for image in imageCollection {
            var i = 0
            originPositions.append(imageCollection[i].center)
            i+=1
    [...]
        }
    }`

Comment: try like this:  var originPositions=[CGPoint]()
        
        override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
            
            
            
            for image in imageCollection {
                originPositions.append(image.center)
            }

Comment: Ha! Now it works smoothly like intended. Great! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to hear that :-)

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @Dasem, I was able to come up with the following answer to the problem:

- Make originPositions an array append position values to the
- originPositions array bring image back when moved with for looping
- using an index

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var imageCollection: [UIImageView]!
    var originPositions=[CGPoint]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        for image in imageCollection {

            originPositions.append(image.center)

            print(originPositions)

            let recognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.handlePan))
            recognizer.delegate = self
            image.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)

        }

    }

     func handlePan(sender:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

        let translation = sender.translationInView(self.view)

        if let view = sender.view {
            view.center = CGPoint(x:view.center.x + translation.x,
                                  y:view.center.y + translation.y)
            sender.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)
        }
        if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended {

            for i in 0 ..< imageCollection.count {
                imageCollection[i].center = originPositions[i]
            }
        }
    }
}
```